# Getting country name from longitude and latitude

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to extract the country name from the latitude and longitude of the location in my dataframe.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
{'Country/Region': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
         'Lat': {0: '33.93911',
          1: '41.1533',
          2: '28.0339',
          3: '42.5063',
          4: '-11.2027'},
         'Long': {0: '67.709953',
          1: '20.1683',
          2: '1.6596',
          3: '1.5218',
          4: '17.8739'},
         'Province/State': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}}
```

Note: this is a pandas dataframe that I only converted to a dictionary for the purpose of asking this question.

This is what I have tried:

```
df[['Lat','Long']].apply(lambda x,y : geocoder.osm([x,y], method='reverse'),axis=1)
```

From this I got this error message:

```
TypeError: ("<lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: I think your lambda should be taking 2 args?

Comment: `df[['Lat','Long']].apply(lambda x,y : geocoder.osm([x,y], method='reverse'), axis=1)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang edited my answer with your suggestion, still get a similar error

Comment: @SuperStormer Thanks for noticing that, edited question

Comment: `df[['Lat','Long']].apply(lambda x : geocoder.osm(list(x), method='reverse'), axis=1)

Comment: You need to read the docs for `apply` and do some basic testing of your assumptions about how it works.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` in your lambda will be a row from the dataframe, this is what you need to do

```py
df.apply(lambda row : geocoder.osm([row['Lat'], row['Long']], method='reverse'), axis=1)
```

if your dataset is large consider using [pandarallel](https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel)

Comment: In fact you can drop `[['Lat','Long']]` now.

Comment: thanks, out of curiosity, why is very slow with larger databases?

Comment: @Emm `apply` in pandas run sequentially so you wouldn't be utilizing all the cores, if you are using a public geocoding service then watch out to not hit the limit though